# What are non-Federation civilizations' positions on genetic enhancement?

Tags: star-trek

The Federation has a very hard stance against genetic augmentation, stemming from the Eugenics Wars and the actions of Khan Singh. We know that utilizing the abilities of augmented people can be a significant strategic advantage, given their (limited) use during the Dominion War.

How do other groups (Romulans, Klingons, etc) view the subject? Is it illegal or frowned upon there as well?

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. There are a lot of non-Federation civilizations featured at one time or another. We know some of them accept genetic augmentation, some reject it, and the vast majority have no stated opinion. As it is, this question seems too broad.

Comment: I wonder what the position of the Cytherians, Excalbians, and the old Greek gods would be.

Answer (score 2):

In ENT: Affliction and ENT: Divergence, it's made clear that the Klingons are willing to experiment with genetic augmentation.